# The display by Bokeh of the geographical map is not the one expected. Why is this?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

Importation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Importation for figures

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
Display precision in relation with the jupyter cell.
output_notebook()
```

Load data

```
df = pd.read_csv("locations.txt", sep = "\t")
df.rename({'lat ':'lat'}, axis =1, inplace=True)
df.head(5)
```

locations.txt is:

```
location_name   lat     lng
0   malomo, Malawi  -1.477887e+06   3.764225e+06
1   El Carrizal, Mexico     2.342341e+06    -1.117616e+07
2   Linakeng, Thaba Tseka, Lesotho  -3.448365e+06   3.222031e+06
3   Villa Hermosa de Buenos Aires, Costa Rica   1.191516e+06    -9.511440e+06
4   Rike, Georgia   5.115103e+06    4.988241e+06
5   Villa Rey, Echague, Isabela, Philippines    1.879689e+06    1.356688e+07
6   Shyorongi/Rurindo, Rwanda   -2.067911e+05   3.336535e+06
7   Tapikilares, Honduras   1.677678e+06    -9.770141e+06
8   Chulucanas, Peru    -5.677682e+05   -8.923326e+06
9   Gabunon Tambulig ZDS, Philippines   9.033059e+05    1.375045e+07
10  Dafara, Mali    1.362784e+06    -8.757134e+05
11  Allah Ditta, Pakistan   3.589045e+06    8.215481e+06
12  Selenge, Mongolia   6.447302e+06    1.184923e+07
13  Santiago, Chile     -3.955039e+06   -7.866867e+06
14  Kfarshima, Lebanon  4.004238e+06    3.955856e+06
15  Mean Chhey District, Cambodia   1.292352e+06    1.168304e+07
```

Importation of get_provider

```
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet

source = ColumnDataSource(df)
```

Creating CARTODBPOSITRON from get_provider

```
tuile = get_provider('CARTODBPOSITRON')
```

Instanciation for figure

```
p = figure(x_range = (-1000000, 7000000), # scale
           y_range = (-7000000, 9000000), # scale
           x_axis_type = 'mercator',      # precision
           y_axis_type = 'mercator')      # //
```

Add

```
p.add_tile(tuile)
```

Instanciation of the point cloud

```
p.circle(x = 'lng',           # abscisses
         y = 'lat',           # ordonnées
         fill_color = 'blue', # couleur de remplissage des cercles
         size = 10,           # taille des cercles
         source = source)     # source des données
```

Instanciation forlabels

```
labels = LabelSet(x = 'lng',              # abscisses
                  y = 'lat',              # ordonnées
                  text = 'location_name', # texte à afficher
                  x_offset = 5,           # décalage sur l'axe des abscisses du label
                  y_offset = 5,           # décalage sur l'axe des ordonnées du label
                  source = source)        # source des données
```

Display figure

```
show(p)
```

[image]

Up here that works OK but when adding labels that fails as you can see below:

```
p.add_layout(labels)  
show(p)
```

[image]

The expecting result is something as:

[image]

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Regards,
Atapalou

Comment: I run you code and it was working. Which version do you use? The newest version is bokeh 2.4.3, try to update you package. Hopefully this will work afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I use Bokeh 2.4.3 too.

Comment: Do you see any error message in your browser console?

Comment: No I don't see any error.

Comment: I try pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.5g}'.format) hoping some improvement but this is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I reordered your script and I hope that this solves some error. Please check out if this works, because it is working for me.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

data = """
location_name   lat     lng
0   malomo, Malawi  -1.477887e+06   3.764225e+06
1   El Carrizal, Mexico     2.342341e+06    -1.117616e+07
2   Linakeng, Thaba Tseka, Lesotho  -3.448365e+06   3.222031e+06
3   Villa Hermosa de Buenos Aires, Costa Rica   1.191516e+06    -9.511440e+06
4   Rike, Georgia   5.115103e+06    4.988241e+06
5   Villa Rey, Echague, Isabela, Philippines    1.879689e+06    1.356688e+07
6   Shyorongi/Rurindo, Rwanda   -2.067911e+05   3.336535e+06
7   Tapikilares, Honduras   1.677678e+06    -9.770141e+06
8   Chulucanas, Peru    -5.677682e+05   -8.923326e+06
9   Gabunon Tambulig ZDS, Philippines   9.033059e+05    1.375045e+07
10  Dafara, Mali    1.362784e+06    -8.757134e+05
11  Allah Ditta, Pakistan   3.589045e+06    8.215481e+06
12  Selenge, Mongolia   6.447302e+06    1.184923e+07
13  Santiago, Chile     -3.955039e+06   -7.866867e+06
14  Kfarshima, Lebanon  4.004238e+06    3.955856e+06
15  Mean Chhey District, Cambodia   1.292352e+06    1.168304e+07
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep = "\s\s+")
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
tile = get_provider('CARTODBPOSITRON')

p = figure(
    x_range = (-1000000, 7000000),
    y_range = (-7000000, 9000000),
    x_axis_type = 'mercator',
    y_axis_type = 'mercator'
)
p.add_tile(tile)
p.circle(
    x = 'lng',
    y = 'lat',
    fill_color = 'blue',
    size = 10,
    source = source
)
labels = LabelSet(
    x = 'lng',
    y = 'lat',
    text = 'location_name',
    x_offset = 5,
    y_offset = 5,
    source = source
)
p.add_layout(labels)
show(p)
```

Comment: In my code, I replace df = pd.read_csv("locations.txt", sep = "\t") by df = pd.read_csv("locations.txt", sep = "\s\s+", engine='python') In your proposal, I added from io import StringIO and  I inserted , engine='python' as above. That works! Thanks

Comment: If this is the case, you DataFrame was not formatted in the correct way. Glad to help.